# How to get count of comments (Append Changes to Existing text)

Tags: social-comment

I have created a custom list in which I have to show the number of comments on a particular item. I have created a calculated column and configured Append Changes to Existing text.

I can edit the item and comment on it. It shows all the comments on that perticular item. But I want the count of all the comments too. Can anyone help me out?

[image]

When I click on the view entries under the comments column I get all the comments on that item as shown in the image below.

[image]

I want the comments count as 4 from the above image.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by having a column in your list called "# of comments" or something.  Set it initially to zero.  Create a workflow that starts whenever a user makes a change to the element (writes a comment).  This workflow will use the action "do calculation" on the column we just made, by adding 1 to it.  Then, when a user makes a comment, the column will change from a 0 to a 1.

This is assuming the only thing a user can change is adding a comment.  I think any other change will also trigger this workflow.  I suppose you could also try to seperate the edit from the original text, and then only do a calculation if the original and new text are different.